# How to find the value belonging to the final row of a certain year in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of the Euro cup results from 1960-2020.

Here is an example of the tournament in 1960 (only 4 games were played):

| year | home_team | away_team | home_score | away_score | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1960 | Czechoslovakia | Russia | 0 | 3 | Russia |
| 1960 | France | Yugoslavia | 4 | 5 | Yugoslavia |
| 1960 | France | Czechoslovakia | 0 | 2 | Czechoslovakia |
| 1960 | Russia | Yugoslavia | 2 | 1 | Russia |

The winner of the tournament was russia,  who won the final game of 1960.

The same will be true for the other years, where the winner always wins the final game of that year.

How can I get this info for the entire dataframe?

Also, when I groupby year, how can I add this info to a new column called "tournament_winner"?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df['tournament_winner'] = df.groupby('year')['winner'].transform('last')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion!

I used:

euros_winner = euros_df.groupby('year')['winner'].transform('last')
euros_df.insert(11, 'tournament_winner', euros_winner)

And it works!

It adds a new column called tournament_winner to the original dataframe, and its repeating. For example all the values in that column in 1960 is 'Russia', and in 1964, 'Spain', etc.

When I do groupby however I only get numerical values, and there are no string values present in the dataframe. Is there any way I can insert the string values of tournament winners per year to the groupby dataframe?